# How can I create YML script that copy txt file from one place to another?

Tags: ansible

I start to learn Ansible and due to a tutorial exercise I needed to copy and rename afile.txt.
Can someone who is more expert help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Here is the [yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sNEh.png):

```
-name: display return
hosts: all
tasks: 
-name: copy and rename
command mc src=/home/scrapbook/tutorial/afile.txt dest=/home/ubuntu/afile_copy.txt
register: output
-debug: var=output
```

To execute it I use:

```
ansible-playbook -i myhosts test.yml
```

And the error message I get is:

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, test.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 3, column 1

- name: display return
hosts: all
^
```

Comment: Keep in mind that whitespace is critical in yaml.  From your error i can see that you did not properly indent so your yaml isnt valid for ansible syntax.

Answer (score 1):

please make your yaml to be code visible (like you see my yaml code below) So that it's easy to understand.
coming to your YAML, i am sure you missed copy module and some indentation errors also found.

use this sample yaml to copy a file//

```
- name: copy module sample
  hosts: all 
  tasks: 
  - name: Copy file task
    copy:
       src: /srv/myfiles/foo.conf
       dest: /etc/foo.conf
    register: result
  - debug:
       var: result
```

by the way, you can refer ansible module samples in this [document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html).